# android chrome embed video shows in full screen only

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video, embed

I made a static website tool that runs in all major browsers and iPad and Android(chrome).  I show .mp4 video source with a simple embed tag.  This was working just dandy until sometime this weekend.  Come monday testing the video in android chrome, it plays audio only when not full screen, and plays correctly when full screen.  I tested with the html5 video tag I use in other tools and actually same bug.  I converted the video to other formats and codec, same bug.  I tested tools that were completed months ago and working perfectly when sold, same bug.  Seems likely that it started when chrome updated sometime after the 10/11 over the weekend.  But as this project is on the home stretch and I had just debugged the last bugs I am putting it out there hoping for some feedback.  I can't be the only one as it is happening with the video tag as well as the embed tag.  It has to be chrome that changed my code didn't.  Any insights out there?

Comment: video tag stopped playing video for me too unless in full screen on my asus transformer tf101

Comment: thanks that info actually helped because we also use an asus for testing and on my nexus and other devices it is just fine.